# Execute install command in SCCM via Powershell on servers

Tags: powershell, sccm

I want to install particular package on the server via powershell.

```
Get-WmiObject -Namespace  ROOT\ccm\ClientSDK -Class CCM_Application -ComputerName Y31056 | Select-Object AllowedActions, Fullname
```

And i can list which software are installed or not installed on the server. 
So i want to install only specific package on the software center.

```
AllowedActions                                                             Fullname                                                                  
--------------                                                             --------                                                                  
{Install}                                                                  CMTrace                                                                   
{Install}                                                                  SCCMpackageV1                                          
{Install}                                                                  SQL Server 2014 SP2
```

I want run the script to install the SCCMpackageV1 via powershell, but little bit confused how to achieve it.

```
$SoftwareApp = Get-WmiObject -Namespace  ROOT\ccm\ClientSDK -Class CCM_Application -ComputerName Y31056 | Select-Object AllowedActions, Fullname
$SoftwareApp.install.SCCMpackageV1
```

I've google it that simple install command should work, but i did not received any output. Software as well not installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Install method for CCM_Application objects needs parameters to be supplied. Microsoft official document contains really detailed information regarding each parameter and you can refer below link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj902785.aspx

See below code as an example to install application on client machine:

```
$ComputerName = "Y31056"
$AppName = "SCCMPackageV1"

$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName $ComputerName
Invoke-Command -Session $s -Argu $ComputerName,$AppName -ScriptBlock `
{
param ($ComputerName,$AppName)
write-host "Getting Parameters for '$AppName' on $ComputerName"
$Application = Get-WmiObject -computername $ComputerName -Namespace "root\ccm\ClientSDK" -Class CCM_Application | where {$_.Name -like "$AppName"} | Select-Object Id, Revision, IsMachineTarget
$AppID = $Application.Id
$AppRev = $Application.Revision
$AppTarget = $Application.IsMachineTarget
([wmiclass]'ROOT\ccm\ClientSdk:CCM_Application').Install($AppID, $AppRev, $AppTarget, 0, 'Normal', $False) | Out-Null
}
Remove-PSSession $s
```

Comment: Thank you for explanaition, now i fixed the script and am really glad that it working. Once again thanks for your time and provided example.

Comment: Exception calling "Install" : "Invalid parameter "
What is causing this ?